# Want to know about react & redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

What is the basic difference between react and redux? is react and redux is same? why we should use redux? Finally why it's called react-redux?

I want to know this i just confused between this two.

Answer (score 1):

You must be pretty new to web development. First of all, welcome !

React and redux are pretty different beasts, but have often been used together to make state management easier in React apps.

- **React** is a front-end web framework, it allows you to create a wide range of web apps using JSX (React's way of fusing Javascript and HTML). This is a gross oversimplification, I encourage you to read [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).
- **Redux** is a state management library. With it, you can define one or many *stores*, containing a *state* (basically an object that holds any data you need), *actions* (methods to alter or retrieve the current value of the store) and to subscribe the state's changes at a global level. Again, the [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) should have most of the answers you're looking for.

React and redux are often used together, mainly through the use of the [`react-redux` package](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started), since Redux offers a global, reactive state, enabling you to share data between React components anywhere in your app without having to pass props.

Now tough, you could achieve similar functionnality without Redux entirely, using React's own [Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) APIs. Although the logic behind these is a bit more involved, it allows for far more flexibility.